Estimate a vector $\beta=\underbrace{\beta_1}_{\text{sparse}}+\underbrace{\beta_2}_{\text{dense}}$
In high-dimensional settings, we solve the linear regression using the lasso method which relies on the assumption of sparsity,
$$
\hat{\beta}=\underset{\beta\in \mathbb{R}^{p}}{\arg \min}\|Y-X\beta\|_2^2+\lambda\|\beta\|_1 .
$$
Now I am interested in a new model in which $\beta$ is decomposed into a sparse vector and a dense vector
$$
\beta=\underbrace{\beta_1}_{\text{sparse}}+\underbrace{\beta_2}_{\text{dense}},\\
Y=X\beta_1+X\beta_2+\epsilon,
$$
and obtain the estimators
$$
\left(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2\right)=\underset{\beta_1,\beta_2}{\arg \min}\|Y-X\left(\beta_1+\beta_2\right)\|_2^2+\lambda_1\|\beta_1\|_a+\lambda_2\|\beta_2\|_b
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_a$ and$\|\cdot\|_b$ encourage the estimators to be sparse and dense.
I guess this model has been well-studied. Now what is the best outcome of this model? Can you provide me with some relevant papers?

[tag:elastic-net]?

@Sycorax elastic net combines two types of regularization to estimate just $\beta$, but I want to obtain the sparse and dense parts separately.

It is sometimes called "lava regression".
See Applied causal inference powered by ML and AI (V. Chernozhukov et al.), chapter 3, and the references they cite.

That's an interesting resource. They made some computations with R in https://colab.research.google.com/github/CausalAIBook/MetricsMLNotebooks/blob/main/PM2/r_linear_penalized_regs.irnb  and it seems like there is no direct method available. I guess that the use of row augmentation is better than their itterative scheme.

To achieve different degrees of regularisation (and sparsity) for different coefficients you can apply different penalty factors to different coefficients.
The popular glmnet supports this with the term penalty.factor. This factor applies only to both norms and a different mixing is not applied.
So with the currently popular ready made packages for regularised fitting in python and R, you can get to the penalty
$$\lambda_1(\alpha \|\beta_1\|_1+ (1-\alpha) \|\beta_1\|_2 ) + \lambda_2(\alpha \|\beta_2\|_1+ (1-\alpha) \|\beta_2\|_2 ) $$
where the penalty factors $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are different, but not with different mixing $\alpha$. For that you would probably need to write a custom made code.

If you want to make a manual code that includes variable mixing for different coefficients, then you could use the glmnet code along with row augmentation, to get effectively a variable mixing for different coefficients.
